# Function to get selected value from Picker View

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am having trouble creating a function that will return the selected value from a picker wheel on my app.

This is what I have so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lstPriority: UIPickerView!

// Array for picker wheel items
let lstPriorityOptions = ["Low", "Medium", "High"]

// Function to get selected value from picker wheel
public func GetSelected() -> String {
    let pickerView: UIPickerView
    let valueSelected = lstPriorityOptions[row] as String

    return valueSelected
}

// Button click event, this is where I will be calling the above function
@IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: Any) {
    if txtNewItem.text != "" {
        let newToDoItem = ToDoItem(ToDoItemText: txtNewItem.text!, ToDoItemPriority: GetSelected())
        ToDoItemList.append(newToDoItem)

        txtNewItem.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: `let row = lstPriority.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)`

Comment: `listPriorityOptions` is a `[String]` so no need to cast `lstPriorityOptions[row]` to `String`

Comment: Add screen shots or code of the datasource and delegate of the Picker View.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)doneYearPickerAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([strPickerSelectedYearIndex isEqualToString:@""]) {
        self.yearTxt.text = [yearArr objectAtIndex:0];
    }else{
        self.yearTxt.text = [yearArr objectAtIndex:[strPickerSelectedYearIndex intValue]];
    }
    // hides year pickerview
    [_yearPickerView setHidden: YES];
}
```